# How to extract unique events from a log file and count them?

Tags: regex, logging, extract

I have a shoutcast connection log file and want to find out which clients are used and how often. The log file is pretty huge (around 100mb) with entries from the last 3 years. The log entries look like this (IPs have been randomized!):

```
<03/23/13@15:46:25> [dest: 1.187.2.99] starting stream (UID: 25477)[L: 2]{A: Internet%20Explorer%207}(P: 1)
<03/23/13@15:46:34> [dest: 1.187.2.99] connection closed (9 seconds) (UID: 25477)[L: 1]{Bytes: 403705}(P: 1)
<03/23/13@16:24:36> [dest: 1.194.2.16] starting stream (UID: 25478)[L: 2]{A: WMPlayer/10.0.0.364}(P: 1)
<03/23/13@16:40:56> [dest: 1.194.2.16] connection closed (981 seconds) (UID: 25478)[L: 1]{Bytes: 15938209}(P: 1)
<03/23/13@16:41:29> [dest: 1.158.2.39] starting stream (UID: 25479)[L: 2]{A: WinampMPEG/5.50}(P: 1)
<03/23/13@16:41:40> [dest: 1.158.2.39] connection closed (11 seconds) (UID: 25479)[L: 1]{Bytes: 432719}(P: 1)
<03/23/13@17:51:29> [dest: 1.142.2.225] starting stream (UID: 25480)[L: 2]{A: WinampMPEG/5.50}(P: 1)
<03/23/13@18:07:48> [dest: 1.142.2.225] connection closed (979 seconds) (UID: 25480)[L: 1]{Bytes: 15919475}(P: 1)
<03/23/13@18:18:48> [dest: 1.232.2.215] starting stream (UID: 25481)[L: 2]{A: TapinRadio}(P: 1)
<03/23/13@18:19:07> [dest: 1.232.2.215] connection closed (19 seconds) (UID: 25481)[L: 1]{Bytes: 417192}(P: 1)
<03/23/13@18:34:45> [dest: 1.187.2.99] starting stream (UID: 25482)[L: 2]{A: Internet%20Explorer%207}(P: 1)
<03/23/13@18:34:46> [dest: 1.187.2.99] connection closed (2 seconds) (UID: 25482)[L: 1]{Bytes: 282751}(P: 1)
```

I want to extract every unique client and in addition count how often this kind of client is used. For the log above the result should look like that:

```
Internet%20Explorer%207   2
WMPlayer/10.0.0.364       1
WinampMPEG/5.50           2
TapinRadio                1
```

At first, I simply filtered all entries that are useless. (Sorry for [using cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#cat).)

```
cat shoutcast.log | grep "starting stream" > filtered.txt
```

Result looks like that:

```
<03/23/13@15:46:25> [dest: 1.187.2.99] starting stream (UID: 25477)[L: 2]{A: Internet%20Explorer%207}(P: 1)
<03/23/13@16:24:36> [dest: 1.194.2.16] starting stream (UID: 25478)[L: 2]{A: WMPlayer/10.0.0.364}(P: 1)
<03/23/13@16:41:29> [dest: 1.158.2.39] starting stream (UID: 25479)[L: 2]{A: WinampMPEG/5.50}(P: 1)
<03/23/13@17:51:29> [dest: 1.142.2.225] starting stream (UID: 25480)[L: 2]{A: WinampMPEG/5.50}(P: 1)
<03/23/13@18:18:48> [dest: 1.232.2.215] starting stream (UID: 25481)[L: 2]{A: TapinRadio}(P: 1)
<03/23/13@18:34:45> [dest: 1.187.2.99] starting stream (UID: 25482)[L: 2]{A: Internet%20Explorer%207}(P: 1)
```

But what now? I'm a bit lost, how to access the information in the `{A: }` brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this awk line:

```
 awk -F'{A: |}' '/starting/{a[$2]++}END{for(x in a)print x" : "a[x]}' input
```

test with your data:

```
kent$  cat ff
<03/23/13@15:46:25> [dest: 1.187.2.99] starting stream (UID: 25477)[L: 2]{A: Internet%20Explorer%207}(P: 1)
<03/23/13@15:46:34> [dest: 1.187.2.99] connection closed (9 seconds) (UID: 25477)[L: 1]{Bytes: 403705}(P: 1)
<03/23/13@16:24:36> [dest: 1.194.2.16] starting stream (UID: 25478)[L: 2]{A: WMPlayer/10.0.0.364}(P: 1)
<03/23/13@16:40:56> [dest: 1.194.2.16] connection closed (981 seconds) (UID: 25478)[L: 1]{Bytes: 15938209}(P: 1)
<03/23/13@16:41:29> [dest: 1.158.2.39] starting stream (UID: 25479)[L: 2]{A: WinampMPEG/5.50}(P: 1)
<03/23/13@16:41:40> [dest: 1.158.2.39] connection closed (11 seconds) (UID: 25479)[L: 1]{Bytes: 432719}(P: 1)
<03/23/13@17:51:29> [dest: 1.142.2.225] starting stream (UID: 25480)[L: 2]{A: WinampMPEG/5.50}(P: 1)
<03/23/13@18:07:48> [dest: 1.142.2.225] connection closed (979 seconds) (UID: 25480)[L: 1]{Bytes: 15919475}(P: 1)
<03/23/13@18:18:48> [dest: 1.232.2.215] starting stream (UID: 25481)[L: 2]{A: TapinRadio}(P: 1)
<03/23/13@18:19:07> [dest: 1.232.2.215] connection closed (19 seconds) (UID: 25481)[L: 1]{Bytes: 417192}(P: 1)
<03/23/13@18:34:45> [dest: 1.187.2.99] starting stream (UID: 25482)[L: 2]{A: Internet%20Explorer%207}(P: 1)
<03/23/13@18:34:46> [dest: 1.187.2.99] connection closed (2 seconds) (UID: 25482)[L: 1]{Bytes: 282751}(P: 1)

kent$  awk -F'{A: |}' '/starting/{a[$2]++}END{for(x in a)print x" : "a[x]}' ff
WMPlayer/10.0.0.364 : 1
TapinRadio : 1
WinampMPEG/5.50 : 2
Internet%20Explorer%207 : 2
```